# How syn log with input type in checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I adopted the code given in this example:
https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

The data is as follows:

```
---------------------------
|    id   |     data      |  
---------------------------
|    1    |    orange     | 
|    2    |     apple     | 
|    3    |    banana     | 
---------------------------
```

The code is as follows (HTML with Javascript):

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div class="log">Log Text</div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <input class="one" type="text" value="" >
</form>
<script>
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".log" ).html( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".one").val(value);
}).keyup();
</script>
```

The picture is as follows:

[image: The picture is as follows]

When I click on the data, Inputs **(checkbox)** are not synchronized with **Log Text**.

What could be the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just add    to the Html <head> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script></head>and it will work

Comment: I've put that code in, but it hasn't changed and I want the log to be the same with Input: apple=apple,
http://s6.picofile.com/file/8382885376/data.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you present in the image is happening when you first check banana, then check orange, and then uncheck orange, or check orange and than check banana.

I'll point out several things:

1. Why you used 2 click events on the same selection (`$("input")`)
   instead doing everything in one function?
2. Since you used checkboxes, and your selection is based on `input` and `input:checked`, when is more than 1 checkbox checked, with `input:checked` you select only the first checkbox that is checked, and not the last one the user clicked.
3. In the 2nd click function you used `keyup()` and I don't see a reason to do so.
4. Since you are selecting `input` (which is a tag name) it effects EVERY input, Including the `one` input. which means that every time the user click the `one` input, the click functions are called for no reason.
5. Since you used `click` event, the click function is called even when you unckeck item, which is odd (unless it was your intention).

In the below snipped I fixed all the issues I mentioned above, and it simple and working. I hope you learn from it :D

```js
$(".checkFruit").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".log").html(value + " is checked!");
    $(".one").val(value);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input class="checkFruit" type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkFruit" type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkFruit" type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div class="log">Log Text</div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <input class="one" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use it like in the log?
$( "input:checked" ).val()

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div class="log">Log Text</div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <input class="one" type="text" value="" >
</form>
<script>
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".log" ).html( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    var value = $( "input:checked" ).val();
    $(".one").val(value);
}).keyup();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and run the code snippet i provided you with i just added https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js and it works fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div class="log">Log Text</div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <input class="one" type="text" value="" >
</form>
<script>
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".log" ).html( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".one").val(value);
}).keyup();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```